# What could cause the wrong ID to be inserted?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, identity

I have a SQL Server 2008 server (build 10.0.5500).  Earlier this week I ran this on a table **that already had data in it**:

```
delete from dbo.table
go    
dbcc checkident('dbo.table',reseed,0)
```

When the user went to create a new record later on, somehow an ID of 0 was inserted into the ID column, instead of the 1 SQL Server usually puts in if identity(1,1) is configured for the ID.

This caused some weird issues, but clearing the data and running the reseed resulted in a 1 being inserted, as expected.  I can't duplicate the issue.

For reference, here's the general format for our save sp's:

```
alter procedure dbo._TableSave
    @pk_id int,
    @field varchar(50)
as
    if (@pk_id is null)
    begin
        set nocount on;

        insert into dbo.Table
        (
            Field
        )
        values
        (
            @field
        );
        select scope_identity();
    end
    else
    begin
        update dbo.Table
        set Field=@field
        where PK_ID=@pk_id

        select @pk_id
    end
```

Does anyone know what could cause SQL Server to insert a 0 in the ID when it should have been a 1?

We are not inserting data into identity columns (with *identity_insert* on) anywhere in the application.

Answer (score 10):

Doing `dbcc checkident('dbo.table',reseed,0)` will cause the next entry in a newly created / truncated table to have 0 as the identity.

```
        CREATE TABLE TestIdent
        (
            ID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_TestIdent PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1,1)
            , SomeText nvarchar(255)
        );

        dbcc checkident('dbo.TestIdent',reseed,0)

        INSERT INTO TestIdent VALUES ('Test');

        SELECT * FROM dbo.TestIdent;
```

[image]

This causes the next identity entered to be 10:

```
        TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.TestIdent;

        DBCC CHECKIDENT('dbo.TestIdent',reseed,10)

        INSERT INTO TestIdent VALUES ('Test');

        SELECT * FROM dbo.TestIdent;
```

[image]

Comment: Only if the table is newly created or has been truncated. If you insert a row and delete it you get a different result `CREATE TABLE dbo.[table] (id int identity(1,1));INSERT INTO dbo.[table] DEFAULT VALUES;DELETE FROM dbo.[table];dbcc checkident('dbo.table',reseed,0);INSERT INTO dbo.[table] OUTPUT inserted.* DEFAULT VALUES;DROP TABLE dbo.[table]`

Comment: I concur, Martin.  I believe the only way to get a 0 in an identity field would be to start with an empty/truncated table.

Comment: @MartinSmith deleting the record and reseeding is the pattern that i've been following. Truncate doesn't work on most of our tables since they have FK relationships.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest the following code to prevent it from happening:
(Instead of the code you posted in your question)

```
DELETE FROM dbo.table
GO
IF EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM sys.identity_columns 
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.table') 
        AND last_value IS NOT NULL
)
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.table', RESEED, 0);
```

It should prevent the "reseeding-to-0".

Explanation:
(I have found no official documentation to support it...)
The problem is with the table `sys.syscolpars` in a column named `idtval`
that is the column which holds ALL the identity column information.
since that table has a row for each column in the database (not only identity columns),
a `NULL` value in that field will represent a non-identity column
(unlike `sys.identity_columns` which uses `NULL` for a new\truncated table).

`sys.syscolpars` uses a different method for holding the information:
it uses the `0x01000000010000000100000001` format (example of identity(1,1) newly created),
with the left 8 digits(position 1-8 after the `0x`) for `Last_Value`,
the next 8 digits (position 9-16 after the `0x`)for `increment_value`,
the next 8 digits (position 17-24 after the `0x`)for `seed_value`,
the 2nd digit from the right is a mystery to me,
and the 1st digit from the right - tells us if it is a new table(=1) or not!

back to our issue -
when `DBCC CHECKIDENT` is run, it checks `sys.identity_columns.last_value`
if it is `NULL` then it updates the new value of `sys.syscolpars.idtval` with `1` in the right position.
`sys.identity_columns.last_value` remains `NULL`.
that causes the next insert identity value to be treated as in a new table.
(I assume `sys.identity_columns` is independent of `sys.syscolpars` because the first is updated immediatly, and the latter is only updated after a checkpoint is performed).

Since there is no way of querying `sys.syscolpars` in real time (it requires DAC),
my suggestion is the condition above, maybe with the addition of `ELSE` clause.

again, i cannot guarantee that any of this explanation is true, but it does work :)

If anyone has a more accurate information about the `DBCC CHECKIDENT` background operation,
i would love to learn, please share!

Good luck,
רועי גביש

Answer (score 0):

```
dbcc checkident('dbo.table',reseed,0)
```

this command cause the new identity value to set to 0.
I have faced the same problem.

then i apply reseed identity to 1 like this

```
  dbcc checkident('dbo.table',reseed,1)
```

Comment: yes, the first one sets the id to 0, so when the next record is inserted sql server takes the current id, adds 1, and gets 1.  the next one the first id i would get is 2.