# DBCC CHECKIDENT behaving inconsistently

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, identity

I have a script that sometimes needs to be run on a fresh database that's just had all the tables created and sometimes needs to be run on an existing database. I have a script to wipe out the tables and update with the latest versions of the reference tables so that This one script can be updated and stored in a source repo to be used on whatever db server needs to run it.

I have a problem with DBCC CHECKIDENT reseeding to use 0 if This is the first run on a fresh database or reseeding to 1 (the desired result) if it is a subsequent run of the same script on the database.

The relevant code at the beginning of the script

```
-- disable all constraints
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"

-- delete data in *ALL* tables (not just refTables)
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable "DELETE FROM ?"
-- reseed the indexes so primary keys start over at 1
declare @cmd varchar(4000)
declare cmds cursor for 
select 'DBCC CHECKIDENT(''' + t.name + ''', RESEED, 0);'
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.identity_columns AS i
ON t.object_id = i.object_id

open cmds
while 1=1
begin
    fetch cmds into @cmd
    if @@fetch_status != 0 break
    exec(@cmd)
end
close cmds;
deallocate cmds
```

How can I get this to behave consistently on initial and subsequent runs so that I don't break foreign keys by having row 1 becoming row 0?

Comment: why delete From X instead of truncate ? why not just let it reseed to the best value with only DBCC CHECKIDENT (table)?

Comment: What version of sql server you are using? ALso, why are you using msforeachtable - undocumented and unreliable ?

Comment: truncate has issues with foreign keys I believe was the original reason for not going that route.

@Kin 2014

Comment: Seems like [a duplicate of this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/39824/1186), and particularly check the details in [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/40812/1186).

Comment: the second answer there, while not exactly the same did help me fix this. I just needed to add WHERE last_value IS NOT NULL after the object_id line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- disable all constraints
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"

-- delete data in *ALL* tables (not just refTables)
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable "DELETE FROM ?"
-- reseed the indexes so primary keys start over at 1
declare @cmd varchar(4000)
declare cmds cursor for 
select 'DBCC CHECKIDENT(''' + t.name + ''', RESEED, 0);'
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.identity_columns AS i
ON t.object_id = i.object_id
WHERE last_value IS NOT NULL

open cmds
while 1=1
begin
    fetch cmds into @cmd
    if @@fetch_status != 0 break
    exec(@cmd)
end
close cmds;
deallocate cmds
```

adding WHERE last_value IS NOT NULL as suggested by the second answer in the question Aaron Bertrand linked too solved this issue.